# HyperThreading и аппаратная виртуализация

Tags: виртуализация

Я бы хотел иметь возможность запускать две операционки сразу, но без использования `эмуляторов`, так, чтобы не одна выполнялась внутри другой с большими задержками, а обе они выполнялись на одном уровне на реальном железе, и задержек из-за его эмуляции бы не было.
Я знаю общие сведения об `аппаратной виртуализации`, но пока я о ней только слышал, потому что считал, что мои ноутбуки ее не поддерживают и я не могу ничего пробовать. Однако в одном месте было сказано, что

> Технология `HyperThreading` в широком смысле также представляет собой
>   аппаратную технологию виртуализации, поскольку при ее использовании в
>   рамках одного физического процессора происходит симуляция двух
>   виртуальных процессоров в рамках одного физического с помощью техники
>   `Symmetric Multi Processing` (SMP).
>
> Виртуализация представляет собой эмуляцию нескольких виртуальных
>   процессоров для каждой из гостевых операционных систем. При этом
>   технология виртуального SMP позволяет представлять несколько
>   виртуальных процессоров в гостевой ОС при наличии технологии
>   HyperThreading или нескольких ядер в физическом процессоре.

Звучит размыто, как будто для поддержки аппаратной виртуализации достаточно только этого. Вдобавок есть еще это:

> `XenServer` requires at least two separate physical x86 computers: one
>   to be the XenServer host and the other to run the XenCenter
>   application. The XenServer host computer is dedicated entirely to the
>   task of running XenServer — hosting VMs — and is not used for other
>   applications

То есть тут уже необходимыми становятся два компьютера, а не один с HT. Причем серверный по спецификации может (должен) иметь до 1Тб RAM, до 160 процессоров и т.п. Это уже серверная корзина полноценная, для того, чтобы держать на ней кучу виртуальных ОС промышленного характера.
**А если я хочу просто иметь дома две одновременно запущенных ОС, между которыми мог бы легко переключаться, но при этом не эмулировать ни одну из них? Есть ли более пользователь-ориентированные решения?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HyperThreading - не имеет отношения к виртуализации. Это просто такая технология в процессоре, которая позволяет сделать дешево больше ядер по той причине, что часть процессора (АЛУ) простаивала, пока другая (конвеер, доступ к памяти) была сильно нагружена. В результате нагруженную часть сдублировали, а АЛУ (Арифметическое логическое устройство) расшарили. И если сильно-сильно АЛУ не грузить, то никто и не поймет ничего (производительность будет не хуже, а цена - лучше). Но на первых порах это было не так и даже некоторые люди отключали HyperThreading.

> А если я хочу просто иметь дома две одновременно запущенных ОС,

Используйте Xen, но насколько это "просто и для домашнего использования" - я не знаю. К тому же, думаю, будут проблемы с видеокартами и другими общими ресурсами.

> Есть ли более пользователь-ориентированные решения?

Как по мне, то virtual box - самое лучшее решение. Или просто паралельная установка двух операционных систем. А в некоторых случаях самое лучшее решение - просто докупить ещё один ноут (да, я понимаю, это деньги, но иногда это окупается. У меня лично один ноут "стационарный", а один маленький, для путишествий).

**Upd**

А есть ещё одна штука - kvm (по этому слову хорошо ищется) - это специальное устройство, к котором с одной стороны подключается монитор, клавиатура, мышка, наушники, с другой стороны два и более декстопа. В результате просто одной кнопкой можно переключатся.

Comment: Virtual Box это же вроде эмулятор? В нем всегда что-нибудь тормозит. Параллельная установка... у меня их и так три установлено, но это же не позволяет их параллельно запускать! Два ноутбука у меня тоже есть, на одном Windows XP, openSUSE и Tiny Core, на втором Windows 7. И даже сижу иногда за обоими, но вот хотелось выяснить, может, есть что-нибудь более технологичное - и доступное мне.

Comment: То есть теоретически можно разместить два десктопа в одном корпусе и где-то там же прикрутить это устройство? Интересно.

Comment: Тормозит, если памяти гиг-другой. Если поставить нормально, хотя бы 12, а лучше 16 гигов, то виртуалбокс работает прилично.

> То есть теоретически можно разместить два десктопа в одном корпусе и где-то там же прикрутить

можно. Возможно подойдут серверные решения. Есть интересная статья с хабра http://habrahabr.ru/post/210668/ - если к этом решению прикрутить kvm - возможно будет то, что Вам нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Решение в данном случае одно, и оно называется Клиентский (Десктопный) Гипервизор [ссылка1](https://ko.com.ua/klientskie_gipervizory_53939), [ссылка2](https://www.vmgu.ru/news/virtual-computer-nxtop) и вряд ли когда вы застанете реальный аппаратный гипервизор - таких в природе я еще не то что не видел и не слышал... Это было бы дорого, не гибко, бесперспективно. А вот идея клиентского гипервизора очень даже перспективна, но разработчикам так не показалось и они вроде все задвинули эту идею далеко и подальше. К нашему сожалению...